# store in the session the last website URL before a login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to redirect a user to his last URL visited before he logged in.

How do I do that?

What I tried:

Added before_filter in my application controller:

```
before_filter :store_location

def store_location
    session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
end
```

But then I also had this before:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    me_path
  end
```

I struggling to understand how these work together.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article on Devise Wiki:

- [How To: Redirect back to current page after sign in, sign out, sign up, update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)

In your case, I think defining `after_sign_in_path_for` like this will work fine:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:user_return_to] || me_path
end
```

Besides, it's safer to filter out `/users` path like this:

```
def store_location
  session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath || unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
end
```

Because this method is also triggered on user sign out, in which case you obviously don't want to redirect them back to an /users page.